# fullcalendar - is there a way to replace the contents of day headings in list view?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

[day headings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ud8EQ.jpg)

hello. I was wondering if any of you know how to change fullcalendar's day headings in list view? I've searched the docs back and forth and so far have gotten nothing yet.

a bit about what i'm trying to do. I'm making a daily activity report app, so that users can fill in their attendance & record their activities, and will be reviewed by admins afterwards. these admins can set which days are working days and are not. in a single day, there can only be a single event, which is the user's daily report. in the event object given to fullcalendar, I pass the type of day.

I wanted to differentiate how headings look for those two types of days. I've tried [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventRender) and get the previous sibling, the header, but turns out they aren't loaded together yet and thus not detected.

an alternative method was modifying the list after it's done loading, but I haven't found the event listener for that yet.

i'm using fullcalendar v4. here's list view docs : https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/list-view

**[EDIT]** here's a codepen to fiddle around in : https://codepen.io/hmsungkar/pen/mdPoaYQ (copied from docs above, changed view & events to fit my needs)

```
var eventsJSON = [
    {
      "title": "Event #1",
      "start": "2020-09-01"
    },
    {
      "title": "Event #2",
      "start": "2020-09-02"
    },
]
var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
    plugins: [ 'list' ],
    timeZone: 'UTC',
    defaultView: 'listMonth',

    header: {
      left: 'title',
      center: '',
      right: ''
    },
    events: eventsJSON
});
calendar.render();
```

thank you. sorry if it's a bit messy.

Comment: Please [edit] to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. Thanks!

Comment: Do the non-working days follow a common pattern? If so you could use the BusinessHours feature to set which days are working and which aren't

Comment: @ADyson currently they're only weekends. but the plan is they can be set by admins. Looked into businessHour, it doesn't seem to be what i'm looking for. but thanks, maybe i'll use in another project when needed

Comment: @DCCoder thanks, i've added a codepen and the code in the question above

Comment: Background Events is another option you can use to differentiate the days.